# javascript input value empty after assignment

Tags: javascript, html

very basic question; I bet it was already asked here but really couldn't find it.

okay so I have a little html form with a hidden input:

```
<input type='hidden' id='switchtonew' name='new' value='no'>
```

and a button that shall change the value of my hidden input to 'yes', via a function because its doing a couple more things, but these work...:

```
<button onclick='maneu()'>switch</button>
```

and the function:

```
function maneu(){
  [...]
  document.getElementById('switchtonew').value = 'yes';
}
```

and now if you click the button, the value of my hidden input just vanishes.

why?
I did try `element.setAttribute('value', 'yes');` too.

Im really confused, please help :(

EDIT: changed function name to real, used one. still not working.

Comment: `switch` is a reserved keyword. Try using another name for your function.

Comment: Try using a syntax highlighter. When you use a reserved word like this it will be obvious. I'm always forgetting that I can't use `delete` or `class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, sorry for bothering.
As it's always, you ask something and find the solution immediately by yourself.
my function is emptying a couple of inputs by looping through them, and setting styling options.

thus, I set the value to yes and immediately afterwards it deletes all values of input tags.

sorry. Im stupid.

Comment: Is it really answer for original question?)

Comment: yes you see:

    `document.getElementById('switchtonew').setAttribute('value', 'yes');
    for(input of document.getElementsByTagName('input')){
     if(input.type != 'checkbox'){
      input.value = '';
     }else{
      input.removeAttribute('checked');
     }
    }`

Comment: `input.value = '';` is the essential part. styling fails in comments sorry

Answer (score 3):

You are using a reserved word `switch`. By renaming the function, it should work.

You could use `type="button"` for the button to prevent submitting.

```js
function switchValue() {
    document.getElementById('switchtonew').value = 'yes';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="switchValue()" type="button">switch</button>
<!-- type is text for displaying the value -->
<input type="text" id="switchtonew" name="new" value="no">
```

Comment: function name switch was only here as an example. the real function name is `maneu()`.

Answer (score 1):

is the button submitting a form?
Probably the page is reloading and the inputs reset, if that is the case, use an `<a>` instead of a `<button>` or add an `event.preventDefault()` to button action

Answer (score 1):

By default button type is `submit`, hence:

```
<button onclick='yourSwitch()'>switch</button>
```

will submit your form, and as result, you will see `yes` in URL (in case you use `GET` form method), like:

```
yourhost.com/index.html?new=yes
```

After reload, your page will come to initial state, which is:

```
<input type='hidden' id='switchtonew' name='new' value='no'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
function maneu() {
  var currentValue = document.getElementById('switchtonew').value;
  if (currentValue === 'yes') {
    document.getElementById('switchtonew').value = 'no';
  } else if (currentValue === 'no') {
    document.getElementById('switchtonew').value = 'yes';
  }
  console.log('value is now: ' + document.getElementById('switchtonew').value)
}
```

```html
<button onclick='maneu()'>switch</button>

<input type='hidden' id='switchtonew' name='new' value='no'>
```